# R: using rvest and purrr:map_df to build a data frame: how to deal with incomplete input

Tags: r, rvest, purrr

I am webscraping webpages with `rvest` and turning the collected data into a dataframe using `purrr::map_df`. The problem I ran into is that not all webpages have content on every `html_nodes` that I specify, and `map_df` is ignoring such incomplete webpages. I would want `map_df` to include said webpages and write `NA` wherever a `html_nodes` does not match content. Take the following code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

urls <- list("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FC_Barcelona",
             "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome", 
             "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curic%C3%B3")
h <- urls %>% map(read_html)

out <- h %>% map_df(~{
  a <- html_nodes(., "#firstHeading") %>% html_text()
  b <- html_nodes(., "#History") %>% html_text()
  df <- tibble(a, b)
})
out
```

Here is the output:

```
> out
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  a            b      
  <chr>        <chr>  
1 FC Barcelona History
2 Rome         History
```

The problem here is that the output dataframe does not contain rows for websites which have not match for the `#History` html node (in this case, the third url). My desired output, looks like this:

```
> out
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  a            b      
  <chr>        <chr>  
1 FC Barcelona History
2 Rome         History
3 Curicó       NA
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check in the `map_df` portion. Since `html_nodes` returns `character(0)` when it's not there, check the lengths of `a` and `b`

```
out <- h %>% map_df(~{
  a <- html_nodes(., "#firstHeading") %>% html_text()
  b <- html_nodes(., "#History") %>% html_text()

  a <- ifelse(length(a) == 0, NA, a)
  b <- ifelse(length(b) == 0, NA, b)

  df <- tibble(a, b)
})
out

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  a            b      
  <chr>        <chr>  
1 FC Barcelona History
2 Rome         History
3 Curicó       NA
```

Comment: Thanks. This was a duplicate indeed, although the phrasing of the question is quite different. I posted a new question that builds on this one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55962196/r-using-rvest-and-purrrmap-df-to-build-a-dataframe-dealing-with-multiple-ele, if you have any ideas.